# Are there any significant post-processing benefits of migrating from Lightroom 4 to the last standalone iteration (Lightroom 6)?

Tags: lightroom-4, lightroom-6

Are there any significant post-processing benefits--in terms of the user work-flow and features--of migrating from Lightroom 4 to the its last stand-alone iteration (Lightroom 6)?

Comment: That really depends upon how you use LR and whether you would find the additions useful or not. Some folks would consider them significant and others would not.

Comment: Does the facility to actually process raws from newer cameras facilitate a post processing benefit?

Comment: I will try to be specific, sorry: Would the last stand alone iteration of Lightroom 6 allow for the processing of imported focus stacked images? I believe Photoshop does this with varying degrees of success, but I am uncertain about Lightroom 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a 30-day free trial and see if LR 6 is worth upgrading. You won't lose your LR 4 library (make a back-up, but I think Lightroom will do that, by default when it makes conversions to the database for LR6). As others have suggested, the benefits to some users may be tiny, but huge for others.

Anyway, given that LR Classic CC 7.2 does NOT have any focus stacking functionality (only Photoshop), I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that the stand-alone version of LR 6 also has no support for focus stacking.